# Let $\sum ^\infty _{n=0}a_nz^n$ be analytic and bounded in $|z|< R$ with $|f(z)|\le M$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $\sum ^\infty _{n=0}a_nz^n$ be analytic and bounded in $|z|< R$ with $|f(z)|\le M$ .then $|a_n|<Mr^{-n}$ where $r<R$ and $n=0,1,2....$

How to prove this i am trying but did  get any idea please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a direct application of [Cauchy's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences). Note that that's valid for *every* $r<R$, not just *some* $r<R$. Indeed, if you tak $r<R$, then$$|a_n|\leqslant r^{-n}\sup_{|z|=r}\bigl|f(z)\bigr|\leqslant Mr^{-n}.$$Note that the equality *may* occur (if $f$ is constant).

Comment: ...sorry i am not understand

Comment: @suresh I've edited my answer.